# Logging different results in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, logging, synchronization

I am debugging some code in my React application and something has caught my attention.
When I log a value (that I am editing), the overall view of the log says: false. When I open the object in the console that same value says true now (see screenshot).

Here's the object copied from the console:

{
"Oid": "a7bab4e4-9d54-4ff5-84eb-7c491a9cbb27",
"TraceCode": "2023000230",
"Finished": true,
"Colli": 1,
"UnitsGross": 2
}

Here's the screenshot: [image]

And here the log in code:

```
function updateDeliveryRules(deliveryrule){
    console.log(deliveryrule);
    rule.DeliveryRules.find((dr) => dr?.Oid === deliveryrule?.Oid).Finished = !deliveryrule?.Finished;
    modifyRule(rule);
}
```